# Is there any way to manage the shape templates other then the default location (Such as placing them inside sub-folders)?

Tags: orchard-modules, orchardcore

I'm developing an Orchard Core site and would like to place the shape templates into some sort of folder structure, if possible?

See example from tutorial:

[image]

So would it be possible to place the ColorField shape templates into a ColorField folder and the PersonPart shape templates into a PersonPart folder?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I was having problems getting Razor pages in a ~/Views/Shared folder to display as a shape.

JTKech replied here to me https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/6376?notification_referrer_id=MDE4Ok5vdGlmaWNhdGlvblRocmVhZDkyNDcxMjQ2NDo3MjcwNjE%3D#issuecomment-640995088. Basically, OC looks at certain folders ("Views", "Views/Items", "Views/Parts", "Views/Fields", "Views/Elements") to display shapes.

That being said, there was a way in O1 to change what folders were searched, and I believe there is such a way in OC but haven't been able to find it.

In the end, you may want to place Color Field and PersonPart into ~/Views/Parts until you find a better solution to suit your needs.

Another option is to create a Theme and place those files within a similar structure there. I tend to do this with front-end views, keeping the Admin/Edit pages in my module. But there's nothing to stop you from doing them either way. Good luck.